# Why is var Int32 not List<Int32> in this example

Tags: c#, linq

Ok I was in the process of getting an answer for another SO question, and I came up with the following function to get a distinct list of int's:

```
    static List<Int32> Example(params List<Int32> lsts)
    {
        List<Int32> result = new List<int>();

        foreach (var lst in lsts)
        {
            result = result.Concat(lst).ToList();
        }

        return result.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
    }
```

When I look at `var` in VS2012, it says its of type `Int32` not `List<Int32>`. Shown here:

[image: The problem]

Shouldn't var be type `List<Int32>` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are missing a `[]` at the end of the parameter type declaration:

```
//                                            v-- this is missing in your code
static List<Int32> Example(params List<Int32>[] lsts)
{
    List<Int32> result = new List<int>();

    foreach (var lst in lsts)
    {
        result = result.Concat(lst).ToList();
    }

    return result.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're being misled by a different compiler error.
Your parameter is not an array.

You need to change the parameter to `params List<Int32>[] lsts` to make it an array of lists.  (or, better yet, `params IEnumerable<Int32>[] lsts`)

Note that you can also get rid of the `foreach` loop completely and write

```
return lsts.SelectMany(list => list)
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(i => i)
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter with the keyword `params` must by an array.